# Reactjs with Laravel REST API: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, laravel-5.3

So I have a project that I am creating with ReactJS. 
I am trying to Log In, and this is my React Code:

```
handleClick(event){
var apiBaseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login";
var self = this;
var payload={
    "email":this.state.email,
    "password":this.state.password
}
axios.post(apiBaseUrl, payload)
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    if(response.data.code == 200){
        console.log("Login successfull");
        var uploadScreen=[];
        uploadScreen.push(<UploadScreen appContext={self.props.appContext}/>)
        self.props.appContext.setState({loginPage:[],uploadScreen:uploadScreen})
    }
    else if(response.data.code == 204){
        console.log("Username password do not match");
        alert("username password do not match")
    }
    else{
        console.log("Username does not exists");
        alert("Username does not exist");
    }
})
.catch(function (error) {
console.log(error);
});
}
```

I am not quite familiar with React and I just got this code [here](https://medium.com/technoetics/create-basic-login-forms-using-create-react-app-module-in-reactjs-511b9790dede)
Just trying it out before I edit it. 
I am trying to access my API which I created with Laravel 5.3 but I get the error:

> Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.
>
> Error: Network Error
>       at createError (createError.js:16)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)

I have searched for answers and they said that I should use CORS. I have Laravel CORS.

my `cors.php` in config

```
'supportsCredentials' => false,
'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
'exposedHeaders' => [],
'maxAge' => 0,
'hosts' => [],
```

Comment: try this https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: I am using that @rkj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

need to stringify the payload.

```
var payload = JSON.stringify({yourdata: yourdata});
```

and also try to add header like this.

```
var config = {
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  withCredentials: false
}

axios.post(apiBaseUrl, payload, config)
```

Comment: i update the answers, try to add stringify at payload variable.

Comment: no need to update, your previous answer worked when I installed the Allow-Control-Allow-Origin:* Extension for Chrome! Thanks!